# Passing a variable to subshell

Tags: bash, subshell

Contrived example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
MYVAR=$(cat /somedir | grep -i myval)
```

Now I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
BASEDIR=/somedir
MYVAR=$(cat [BASEDIR?] | grep -i myval)
```

How should variable be passed to subshell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
#!/bin/sh -
BASEDIR=/somedir
MYVAR=$(grep -rie myval -- "$BASEDIR")
```

Subshells are copies of the parent, they inherit all the memory including variables and most other things.

Note that running `cat` on a directory makes little sense. Here, we're passing the contents of the variable as an argument to `grep` and using the (non-standard) `-r` option so `grep` greps on the files found by a recursive descent of that directory.

Con`cat`enating a single file also makes little sense.

You don't need to install bash for that, your `sh` will do just as well and likely more efficiently.

If you wanted to run `grep` on the concatenation of all the regular files found via a recursive descent of the directory, you'd do:

```
MY_VAR=$(find -- "$BASEDIR" -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -i myval)
```

So beware the files are concatenated in no particular order. With GNU `grep` you can also do:

```
MYVAR=$(grep -rhie myval -- "$BASEDIR")
```

where `-h` skips printing the names of the files where the matching lines are found to achieve something similar. The order may be different, and you may also get differences if some of the files have a non-delimited last lines.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are copied to a subshell. If you change their values, the change is **not** propagated back to the parent.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
tmp=$(mktemp)

echo 123 > "$tmp"

value=$(cat "$tmp")
echo Found $value.

rm "$tmp"
```